# vimrc window split nnoremap doesn't work from eclim project tree view

Tags: vim, eclim

I use `<c-l>` to switch to the window split right of the active window split. I'm having an issue with eclim where `<c-l>` doesn't appear to do anything when the project tree view is the active window using this simple vimrc (note that `<c-w>l` does work):

```
set nocompatible
nnoremap <c-l> <c-w>l
```

However, mapping to another key such as 'n' does change the active split to one window to the right using `<c-n>`:

```
set nocompatible
nnoremap <c-n> <c-w>l
```

I found the following line in `eclim/autoload/eclim/tree.vim`:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <c-l> <c-l>:silent doautocmd eclim_tree User <buffer><cr>
```

Commenting out the line allows me to use `<c-l>`. However, I'm not entirely sure what the previous line is for and what impact commenting it out has. Is there a safer away to work around this while retaining my existing key bindings?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

https://github.com/ervandew/eclim/issues/58